# Probability Interval for Gamma Distribution with Chi squared

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I currently try to transform a Gamma into a Chi-square (X2) and calculate a 95% confidence interval.
So, let's say I have a Gamma distribution of $$Gamma(4.5, 4)$$
Given the answer in 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575050/transforming-gamma-into-chi-squared-distribution
I can transform the gamma into a chi-square by

[image]

To get theta, I do

$$\frac{1}{2\theta}=4$$
$$\theta = \frac{1}{8}$$

Then, I would get

$$8Y = \chi^2(2*4.5) = \chi^2(9)$$

I can get the constants from a X2-table for 9 degrees of freedom with

$$lower = 2.70$$

$$upper = 19.02$$

I would then multiply by 8 to get 
$$P(8*lower < Y < 8*upper)$$
 for the desired interval for the gamma, which is way too large.

However, when I use R to calculate the upper and lower bounds by using

```
alpha <- 4.5 
beta <- 4

alpha_conf <- 0.05
q_lower <- qgamma(alpha_conf / 2, alpha, beta)
q_upper <- qgamma(1 - alpha_conf / 2, alpha, beta)
c(q_lower, q_upper)
```

I get 
$$P(0.3375487 < Y < 2.3778460)$$
which makes much more sense looking at the data. I realized that the constants I got from the X2-table will give me the same result, if I do 
$$P(\frac{1}{8}*lower < Y < \frac{1}{8}*upper)$$

If I use the formula given in
[Probability Interval for Gamma Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80833/probability-interval-for-gamma-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I get yet another solution (alpha and beta are reverse to my syntax, so in that case it would be Gamma(4, 4.5)). With

$$\frac{2*Y}{4} \sim \chi^2(9)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}*Y \sim \chi^2(9)$$,

which, again, would not give me the correct result.

Assuming that the calculations in R are correct, I don't know where my mistake is.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: sure, if that is the only problem that's an easy fix!

Comment: Just figured it out myself. 8*lower = 2.7 => lower = 2.7/8 would be the the lower bound of the original gamma. Simmilarly, for the upper.